# Can you have same Legendary Creature on the battlefield twice utilizing the Mutate ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you have mutated on top of a legendary creature, are you then legally able to cast onto the battlefield another of the same legendary creature card?

Comment: Please note that you are *always* able to cast another legendary with the same name. It will enter the battlefield and trigger its effects. You just don't get to keep both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 702.139e A mutated permanent has all abilities of each card and token that represents it. Its other characteristics are derived from the topmost card or token.

Being legendary is not an ability; rather, it's a supertype:

> 109.3. An object’s characteristics are name, mana cost, color, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, abilities, power, toughness, loyalty, hand modifier, and life modifier. Objects can have some or all of these characteristics. Any other information about an object isn’t a characteristic. For example, characteristics don’t include whether a permanent is tapped, a spell’s target, an object’s owner or controller, what an Aura enchants, and so on.

> 205.4a A card can also have one or more supertypes. These are printed directly before its card types. The supertypes are basic, legendary, ongoing, snow, and world.

That means that if you mutate *on top of* a legendary creature, you can cast it again (if you have another copy in your hand) without it being affected by the legend rule. If you mutate *under* a legendary creature, it's still legal to cast another copy, but it's usually not such a good idea.

Comment: Also, legendary creatures with Mutate could be mutated under an existing creature without conflicting with any versions of themselves that already exist on the battlefield.

Comment: Especially you should be able to mutate a legendary creature under another legendary creature with the same name, correct?